# What is the meaning of -r and -R in copy command?

Tags: cp, recursive

I read that they stand for recursively in the man page.
However, I am not sure what their role is in the command.
When I tried to copy some empty directory into another directory with,

```
$ cp EMPDIR DESTDIR
```

it does not work, with error massage `cp: -r not specified; omitting directory 'empdir'`

but when I executed

```
$ cp -r or -R EMPDIR DESTDIR
```

It works.

What is the exact function of -r and -R?
Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Is you question, “what does *recursive* mean?” — You can edit the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `-r` or `-R` switch tells the `cp` command to copy the directory recursively which includes all files and subdirectories. It is necessary for copying directories but not files.

You are getting the error in your question when you don't use it because you are trying to copy  a directory without using `-r` or `-R`.

The same can be done with `cp --recursive`. This is all covered in the `man` page.